# Changing origin of the floor

Tags: webots

Is it possible to change the origin of a floor from center to say left upper corner in Webots?
For exmaple the size of then rectangular arena is 20x20 and I want to set its origin from 0,0 to 10,10

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by creating your own proto file. I would recommend you to start from an existing proto, for example, `WEBOTS_HOME/projects/objects/floors/protos/Floor.proto`. Copy and rename this file to `MyFloor.proto` for example and edit it to change the coordinates of the `IndexedFaceSet` node. Typically you will have to replace:

```
        geometry IndexedFaceSet {
          coord Coordinate {
            point [
              %{= -(size.x / 2) }% 0 %{= -(size.y / 2) }%
              %{= size.x / 2 }% 0 %{= -(size.y / 2) }%
              %{= -(size.x / 2) }% 0 %{= size.y / 2 }%
              %{= size.x / 2 }% 0 %{= size.y / 2 }%
            ]
          }
```

by:

```
        geometry IndexedFaceSet {
          coord Coordinate {
            point [
              0 0 0
              %{= size.x }% 0 0
              0 0 %{= size.y }%
              %{= size.x }% 0 %{= size.y }%
            ]
          }
```

That will move the floor origin at a corner of the floor.
Also, the boundingObject should be updated so that the floor looks nicer when selected. Replace:

```
    boundingObject Plane {
      size IS size
    }
```

by:

```
    boundingObject Transform {
      translation %{= size.x / 2 }% 0 %{= size.y / 2 }%
      children Plane {
        size IS size
      }
    }
```

Comment: This changed the origin but moved the floor  in a strange way.
you can see the image here in the URL.


https://imgur.com/a/VKzF8Lr

Comment: This shouldn't harm the simulation. But I agree it doesn't look nice when the floor is selected. I updated my answer to explain how to modify the `boundingObject` so that the selected floor corresponds to the actual one, and hence looks nicer when selected.